# I want to use this id of href in the query to display text and image of that category id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to use this `id` of `href` in the query to display text and image of that category `id'.Fetch these details from database in PHP MySQL

```
 echo '<li ><a href="sidebar.php?category='.$row["cid"].'">'.$row2["csname"].'</a></li>
    $query3="SELECT * FROM items where category='sidebar.php?category'";
```

Comment: Add code properly

Answer (score 0):

You may add the category id to the link in some attribute, maybe in the id attribute, and then use AJAX to send that data to a PHP page.

So tweak your HTML tag as follows:

```
<a href="sidebar.php?category='.$row["cid"].'" id="'.$row["cid"].'" class="category_link">
```

Using jQuery, you can handle the AJAX request in this way:

```
jQuery.on("click", function(e) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'backend.php',
      data: {category_id: jQuery(this).attr("id")},
      success: function( data ){
         //now echo the data where you want
         // for example
         $('#result').html( data );
      }
    });
});
```

Then, in you backend PHP page, the query would be like

```
$query3="SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = ".mysql_real_escape($_REQUEST['category_id']);
```